# Changing an xml file in res folder per firebase remote config

Tags: java, android, xml, firebase, firebase-remote-config

I have a quick question regarding the Firebase remoteconfig parameters. In the documentation and videos, it specified that parameters can be added to the MainActivity etc, but my question is: is it possible to use Firebase remoteconfig to change a value in /app/src/main/res/FOLDER/any.xml ?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change resources, because they are read-only; use `SharedPreferences` instead.

Comment: for the next startup of the app, is it possible to transfer the values in Shared Preferences to the resource file?

Comment: @wavesonthaw have you even read my answer? in best case you can initialize `SharedPreferences` from values in the resources, and not the other way around - in case these are user-accessible preferences, one can also define default values for them (this is the most common way).